# Why Nhibernate cannot create this simple query for me?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, antlr

I cannot understand why this simple query is not created. I call this method from a test and it throws an exception complaining about line 1, column 7 where I cannot see anything wrong.

```
    public IList<Continent> GetContinentByName(string name)
      {
       ISession session = GetSession();

       IQuery query = 
                         session.CreateQuery("select from Continent where Continent.ContinentShort='Atlantis'");

// (........) Next step will be getting the list from the query if I can make it work
```

I get antlr exception below

TestCase 'M:DataAccessLayer.HibernateDataProvider.GetContinentByName(System.String)'
failed: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 7
 NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 7

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

session.CreateQuery expexts a HQL query, like this:

`sess.CreateQuery("from DomesticCat cat where cat.Name in (:namesList)");`

If you are trying to push a native SQL query you must do this:

`session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT {cat.*} FROM CAT {cat} WHERE ROWNUM<10", "cat", typeof(Cat))`

However, that would not be a good way to use NHibernate.

See Nhibernate docs for more info: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-querying

Answer (score 1):

I think it's expecting an alias where you have provided the full entity name. Try:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Continent c where c.ContinentShort='Atlantis'");
```

If this doesn't fix the problem please show the mapping for Continent.

Answer (score 0):

O.K.

the problem is the 'select' at the beginning. Seems it is not valid in the version I am using.
So once I have removed the "Select" at the beginning, it worked fine!